# Android: Override onDraw() or run() in order to draw on Canvas

Tags: java, android, canvas

I want to do a simple animation by drawing on canvas in Android Studio. I followed this tutorial series to set up the basic java code (see my own code below):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UH2OWnq7NQ4

He is overwriting the run() method to do all the drawing, however everybody else seems to do it in the onDraw() method. Which method is generally better? Will I run into problems when doing it this way?

```
public class AnimationActivity extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

    Thread thread = null;
    boolean canDraw = false;

    Bitmap backgroundBlack;
    Canvas canvas;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;

    public AnimationActivity(Context context) {
        super(context);
        surfaceHolder = getHolder();
        backgroundBlack = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background_black);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        prepPaintBrushes();

        while (canDraw) {

            if (!surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {
                continue;
            }

            canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            canvas.drawBitmap(backgroundBlack,0,0, null);

            //drawing is done here

            surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void pause() {
        canDraw = false;

        while (true) {
            try {
                thread.join();
                break;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        thread = null;
    }

    public void resume() {
        canDraw = true;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with this particular API, but from my experience with graphics programming, writing your own rendering loop seems very suspicious to me. Calling `sleep()` is also a big no-no. Both of these will lead to an unresponsive UI.

I suggest that you read the documentation and tutorials for `SurfaceView` on [the official Android site](http://developer.android.com).